# Why is relativistic velocity addition not symmetric?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

The Galilean velocity addition formula is $$u' = v + u$$ This is symmetric if one swaps $v$ and $u$.

What are the fundamental reasons why the (generalized) relativistic velocity addition formula is not symmetric?

$$\vec{u}^{\prime}=\frac{\vec{v}\left(1+\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u} /|\vec{v}|^{2}\right)+\left(\vec{u}-\vec{v}(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}) /|\vec{v}|^{2}\right) \sqrt{1-|\vec{v}|^{2}}}{1+\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}}$$

Is it due to the constant, finite speed of light?

Comment: Is there a reason you would expect the situation to be symmetric when taking relativity into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental reason behind the asymmetry is that two Lorentz boosts don’t in general *commute*, just like two 3D spatial rotations don’t in general commute. For Lorentz boosts and for rotations, it matters which one you do *first*, and thus the formula for composing them cannot be symmetric.

In terms of the infinitesimal rotation generators $J_i$ and boost generators $K_i$, the non-commutation of the transformations is clear:

$$[J_i, J_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}J_k$$

$$[K_i, K_j]=-\epsilon_{ijk}J_k$$

$$[J_i, K_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}K_k.$$

Only when the two rotations are around the same axis, or the two boosts are in the same direction, do they commute.

In general, it is *usual* for transformations *not* to commute, and *unusual* for them to commute. Since even 3D rotations are non-commutative, you should not think of the non-commutativity of Lorentz boosts as being due the finite speed of light (although in some sense they are, since Galilean boosts are commutative). I think of the non-commutativity of rotations and Lorentz boosts as being due to the dimensionality of spacetime being high enough to destroy the trivial commutativity in lower dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The relativistic velocity addition formula is $$u’=\frac{u+v}{1+uv/c^2}$$
This is also clearly symmetric if one swaps $u$ and $v$

Comment: I was referring to the generalized version, which is not symmetric. Apologies, I should have been more precise.

Comment: It's true that two boosts in the same direction commute, but two boosts in different directions do not.